# Select query in Hibernate with more then two values

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

How to write a Hibernate query to select values with more then two values?

```
metrics = new long[]{1, 2, 3};
rprtAutoCustomColum = reportSettingServive.getColumnsMap("1,2,3");
```

There are three columnId's. I want to select the columnId and variable name and store in a `HashMap`

```
public Map<Long, String> customeCol = new HashMap<>();

public HashMap<Long, String> getColumnsMap(String columnIds) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<ReportsAutomationCustomColumns> automationCustomColumns = new ArrayList();

    SQLQuery query;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "from lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns  where column_id=:columnIds";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<ReportsAutomationCustomColumns> list = query.list();
        transaction.commit();

        list.stream().forEach((ReportsAutomationCustomColumns clist) -> {
            customeCol.put(clist.getColumnId(), clist.getVariableName());
        });
        return (HashMap<Long, String>) customeCol;
    }
}
```

Normal SQL looks like:

```
select column_id,variable_name from lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns
where column_id in(1,2,3) order by column_id
```

But I want in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `List` with the values you want and then pass it to your query, like this:

```
List<Long> values = new ArrayList<Long>();
values.add(1L);
values.add(2L);
values.add(3L);

String hql = "from lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns  where column_id in (:columnIds)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("columnIds", values);
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, When i tried to run above code its throwing the following exp. ex = (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns is not mapped [from lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns  where column_id in (:columnIds)]

Comment: In HQL, insted of using the table name, you must use the class name that's mapped to that table. (so instead of "lxr_reportsauto_customcolumns", use the class name mapped to it)